# How I can toggle wordpress submenu item hide/show

Tags: css, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress theme and I had created the responcive navbar using CSS.
This is my code:

```
<nav>
    <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
</nav>
```

And this is CSS:

```
nav ul {
      list-style: none;
  }
  nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}


  nav a{
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 40px;
      padding: 0 2em;
      -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  }
  nav a:hover{
      background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
      color: black;
  }
```

My responsive navbar working fine, But I am not understanding how do I hide the submenu items? and only it should be visible when mouse over.

Comment: What is the html injected by `wp_nav_menu()`? Without knowing the actual structure of your html, it is impossible to target the submenu with CSS.

Comment: I had just used wp_nav_menu() to create default html structhure that wordpress offers:

Comment: That's fine, but someone with no wordpress experience can still instruct you on how to hide your submenu by CSS. But without seeing the structure that is impossible. The fact that this is a wordpress site vs a django site vs hand-coded html is not relevant in this case.

Comment: <nav>
    <div class="menu-main-container">
     <ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
       <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-32"><a href="#">Services</a>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65"><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>

</ul>
</div>               
 </nav>

Comment: Ok got it may be I need to edit my question and write the code which I am getting from wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic structure looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Menu item</li>
  <li>Sub-menu
    <ul>
      <li>Sub-menu item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Pretty much what you want to do is hide all sub-menus by default (using `display: none`) and then when the *parent* item is hovered, use `display:block` to make them visible again.

All sub-menus are lists (ul) nested immediately inside of list items. Thus you can target them by identifying all `ul` that are immediate children of `li`:

```
/* Hides all sub-menus */
li > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

Then, when you want to display the sub-menu,you need to target all lists (ul) that are immediate children of list items (li) that are currently being hovered on:

```
/* Show sub-menu when hovering over parent item */
li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

I've included your code below. I modified your HTML by adding additional children and a sub-sub menu. The sub-sub menu is positioned a little strangely but that's due to your existing CSS which I also retained.

```css
/* Submenu */
li > ul {
  display: none;
}

li:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

/* Your original CSS (unchanged) */
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 2em;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
}

nav a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="menu-main-container">
    <ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-32"><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65"><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65"><a href="#">Sub menu 2</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65"><a href="#">Sub menu 3 with sub-sub menu</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65"><a href="#">Sub-sub menu 1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Note that your original code has a class called "sub-menu" on the nested menus. I didn't use this class because I'm not familiar with word-press to know if sub-sub menus will also have this class name, or if it will use something different.

If wordpress does use the `.sub-menu` class consistently, then you can use these rules instead:

```
/* Hides all sub-menus */
.menu-item .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
.menu-item:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your initial CSS on `nav ul li` to this:

```
#menu-main > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The `>` selector ensures you are only targeting the direct decendant child elements of `#menu-main`, the top level `ul`.

Additionally, WordPress will add a `sub-menu` class to the "dropdown" `ul` elements in your menu so target those like this:

```
nav .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
#menu-main > li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

First rule hides those dropdowns, second rule shows the dropdown of a top level nav item that is hovered. I would probably use different values for `display` property but depends on your specific implementation, this should achieve the hide/show.

Comment: Examine your HTML and see what element you can target to consistently reference the top level. The UL/LI scheme will repeat as deep as your menu is nested so watch out for target all `ul`  or `li` elements in your menu. Probably one small adjustment to the selector will make this work for you.

Comment: Yap I understand the problem ... but dont know how to create using    <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>.

Comment: Inspect the resulting HTML, what is immediately inside the `nav` element? Does that element have any class or id on it?